# How can I debug this crash log

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode5, crash-reports

I get this crash log from my device log after that my app is crashed. Before crash I clicked on cancel button from search bar inside `UITableView`.

How can I understand what and where is the problem ?
how can I debug this kind of log from production device?

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b74b1fc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b7b2a4e pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b6fc028 abort + 72
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3ab4a98a abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3ab636e2 default_terminate_handler() + 250
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b19b936 _objc_terminate() + 190
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3ab611b0 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3ab60d12 __cxa_rethrow + 98
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b19b80a objc_exception_rethrow + 38
9   CoreFoundation                  0x30d724e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 638
10  CoreFoundation                  0x30d7224e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
11  GraphicsServices                0x35aac2e6 GSEventRunModal + 134
12  UIKit                           0x33627840 UIApplicationMain + 1132
13  MYAPPNAME                           0x000ffc44 0xfa000 + 23620
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x3b694ab4 start + 0
```

------- EDITED ------

i get Last Exception Backtrace:

```
0   CoreFoundation                  0x30e3ee7e __exceptionPreprocess + 126
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b19b6c2 objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x30e3ed50 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 100
3   Foundation                      0x317e70aa -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 86
4   UIKit                           0x33796348 -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 7940
5   MYAPPNAME                           0x00233972 0xfa000 + 1284466
6   MYAPPNAME                           0x00232e3c 0xfa000 + 1281596
7   MYAPPNAME                           0x00232fd8 0xfa000 + 1282008
8   MYAPPNAME                           0x002319d4 0xfa000 + 1276372
9   Foundation                      0x3181933a __NSFireDelayedPerform + 410
10  CoreFoundation                  0x30e09e7a 
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 10
11  CoreFoundation                  0x30e09a96 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 790
12  CoreFoundation                  0x30e07e1e __CFRunLoopRun + 1214
13  CoreFoundation                  0x30d7246c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
14  CoreFoundation                  0x30d7224e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
15  GraphicsServices                0x35aac2e6 GSEventRunModal + 134
16  UIKit                           0x33627840 UIApplicationMain + 1132
17  MYAPPNAME                           0x000ffc44 0xfa000 + 23620
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x3b694ab2 tlv_initializer + 2
```

Comment: post the full crash log after De-Symbolicated in Xcode

Comment: i get this log from xcode organizer, after de symbolication

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash report as describe in other comments and answers and you'll see which line of code is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The crash happened because of an unhandled exception.

While symbolicating the crash report with the Xcode organizer usually helps, it doesn't help in this case, since stack frame 13 will only show something like `main (main.m:14)`.

If the crash report doesn't contain an `Last Exception Backtrace` section, the report is basically meaningless.

Try to reproduce the crash while running the app with the debugger or integrate a 3rd party crash report solution that is able to provide the `Last Exception Backtrace` and also the `Application Information` section which gives you the detailed exception error.

There are many 3rd party solutions out there, I won't recommend any, since I would be biased :)

**Update:** As you now provided the `Last Exception Backtrace` it shows that there is an Assertion triggered when a tableview animation is ending. Once you symbolicates the crash report you'll see which lines of code in your app are causing this.

Comment: I cannot get the row of exception because "Strip Debug Symbols During Copy" flag was set to YES... like here required http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports

Comment: Symbolicating with the app binary will never give you line numbers. You need the dSYM that was created when that exact build was made. The answer you linked to is wrong, see my comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports#comment21083015_4954949